# How to use Ninject's IsSingletonScope method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, ninject

I have a follwing `Ninject` bindings in my project.

```
    Bind<IThingsDataContext>().To<ThingsDataContext>().InSingletonScope();
    Bind<IThingViewModel>().To<ThingViewModel>();
    Bind<IThingsListViewModel>().To<ThingsListViewModel>();
```

I need to inject `IThingsDataContext` to `ThingViewModel` and `ThingsListViewModel` through constructor, and it has be the same instace of `IThingsDataContext`.

But when I do

```
_kernal.Get<IThingViewModel>();
_kernal.Get<IThingsListViewModel>();
```

I see two different instance of `IThingsDataContext` injected to the viewmodels!
Am I doing something wrong with the bindings or using `IsSingletonScope` incorrectly?

Comment: As far as I can see this should work. Could you please provided a reproduction unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting back into using Ninject so I'm a little rusty, but this but this sounds like the singleton problem I encountered when moving from Ninject 1.0 to 2.0. You can [read more details on my blog](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2009/10/on-becoming-ninject-warrior-and.html), but I think you want to bind ThingsDataContext to itself in singleton context first. Then you can bind IThingsDataContext to the copy of ThingsDataContext that is in the kernel.

```
Bind<ThingsDataContext>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
kernel.Bind<IThingsDataContext>.ToMethod( c => c.Kernel.Get<ThingsDataContext>());
```